# Rails environment broke- need help repairing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

ugh!  In the course of working in my perfectly good rails environment, I did something bad:

- While running my local sandbox, looking in Chrome developer tools/sources (this is for our own codebase), I clicked an item in the sources list and doing so prompted downloading a file: Roboto-Regular-e60d1ba1cef90e4a4da5c9e2fe1ec3b1.woff2
- I got a "threat detected" popup
- I submitted the screen I was on, and saw an error to the effect of 'no data', and rails server had stopped

Now I'm having the following symptoms:

- Typing "rails server" (or even just "rails") gives me a "No such file or directory" error for /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec/rbenv.
- the following script (with no modifications since its original create date last year) has the line looking for that file : /.rbenv/shims/rails
- in the directory in question (libexec), I don't see a plain "rbenv" file, only these with more specific names: rbenv---version, rbenv-help, rbenv-realpath.dylib, rbenv-version, rbenv-version-origin, rbenv-commands, rbenv-hooks, rbenv-root, rbenv-version-file, rbenv-versions, rbenv-completions, rbenv-init, rbenv-sh-rehash, rbenv-version-file-read, rbenv-whence, rbenv-exec, rbenv-local, rbenv-sh-shell, rbenv-version-file-write, rbenv-which rbenv-global, rbenv-prefix, rbenv-shims, rbenv-version-name

I've just used homebrew to upgrade rbenv, but the symptom is still the same.

My $PATH variable has:

```
-bash: /Users/drkaplan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/Users/drkaplan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin:/Users/drkaplan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/Users/drkaplan/.rvm/bin:/Users/drkaplan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin:/Users/drkaplan/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/drkaplan/.rbenv/shims:/Users/drkaplan/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin: No such file or directory
```

Ideas for where to look next?

Comment: Downloading a font file will not corrupt your Rails env. If `rails` isn't resolving, check your `shims` directory. If you cannot find it, try `gem install rails`.

Comment: Wow you're right- reinstalling rails did the trick! I'm up and running again! I could weep!!!! :D

Comment: You might want to step back and read some documentation about Rails, rbenv, and web technology in general. Downloading a .woff file won't impact your dev environment at all. Downloaded any non-executable or any executable and not executing it, should do nothing. So, your env got screwed up some other way. And the way I debugged it may not solve your problem as a whole. `rbenv` is about organizing multiple environments. It's possible that you need to install rails for other versions of ruby depending on the ruby version specified in the `.ruby-version` file.

Comment: That's a good point- I'd been using rbenv a little while back to work on upgrading versions, and was confused why that would have a complaint now. Will have a look at my current versions and see if there are any other clues. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this case was to reinstall rails:

```
gem install rails
```